# How do I measure the accuracy of predicted time series where the most important aspect is if the output is negative or positive?

Tags: python

I have this model that predicts a value into the future and I want to test how accurate it does this by seeing if the result is the same as the actual value by if it has the same sign.  This is all on python.

So if the predicted value is -2 and the actual value is -1 it would count it as correct and add 1 to the dataframe (both negative). But if the predicted value is 2 and the actual is -1 it would add 0 to the dataframe.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be to have two arrays. One array contains the true values(aT), the other contains the predicted values(aP). If you take numpy.sign() of both arrays you will get another array back which contains the signs of the input vector. sgnaT = np.sign(aT), sgnaP = np.sign(aP). Next I would take np.sum(sgnaT==sgnaP) this will tell you how many times in the array the two signs matched. Finally to get a percentage correct I would divide by the total number of samples.

```
import numpy as np
aP = [your predicted values]
aT = [your true values]
sgnaP = np.sign(aP)
sgnaT = np.sign(aT)
totCor = np.sum(sgnaT==sgnaP)
totIncorrect = np.sum(sgnaT!=sgnaP)
perCor = tot/(totCor+totIncorrect)
```

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this?

```
y_pred = [-2, -1, 1 , 3]
y_true = [-2, 1, 1, 4 ]
df = pd.DataFrame({"y_pred":y_pred, "y_true":y_true})
score = (df.y_pred > 0) & (df.y_true > 0)
score.astype(int)

>>> score.astype(int)
0    0
1    0
2    1
3    1
dtype: int64
```